# Change in color of legend not reflected in the plot

Tags: matplotlib

I'm trying to change the colour of the `'0's` in my plot to red. I could change the colour of the legend but this isn't reflecting to that dots in the scatter plot. How do I fix this?
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the data is not available above, I am assuming that `over_50['target']` has only two values - 0 or 1. In that case, you should be using `palette` to assign colors. `legend_handles` will update the colors and not the graph.

I am using a sample code to show this....

```
import seaborn as sns
tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")
sns.scatterplot(data=tips, x="total_bill", y="tip", hue="time", palette = ['r', 'g']) #Red and Green
```

**Output**
[image]